# PC won't POST temporarily after power restored to board

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, power-supply

Not a particularly catchy title.

I have an (unrelated) issue that means I have to kill power to my PC entirely (by switching off the PSU) after shutdown (it turns itself on, I'm not sure why).

Usually I then leave it off overnight, and flick the switch to give power, then press the on button.

Recently, if I don't leave the computer for 3-4 minutes before pressing the on button(after flicking the PSU switch), it will do one of the following:

- Turn on, then immediately turn itself off again, then turn on again, and switch off etc. in a loop
- 'Freeze' on the BIOS logo screen, ctrl+alt+del and power button do nothing, reset will restart it but the same will happen again
- Pause on GPU initialization, where a white underscore will pulse at the top left of my monitor and not continue to boot. I'm able to ctrl+alt+del, shut down and restart with this one
- Freeze during Windows 10 loading. The spinner will stop spinning, and I am unable to restart or shutdown without holding the power button for 5+ seconds.

This has started getting worse recently. After restarting, the machine will continue to display another one of these issues. A BIOS reset will *occasionally* allow it to boot without issue, but most of the time I have to unplug all power, take out the bios battery, and leave it for a good 20-30 minutes.

There are never any issues upon the machine fully booting into Windows, and as far as I can tell I can restart without issue.

This is a fairly new machine bought in January with the following hardware:

```
Intel i7 5820k
16GB Corsair DDR4 Vengeance LPX Black
Gigabyte GA-X99-SLI
AMD Radeon Sapphire 280x
Be Quiet! 1kw Power Zone PSU
```

Possibly related is the fact that my board will no longer post with more than one 280x in. It used to boot fine with both. I can swap them out with each other with no problem, but cannot boot with both plugged in.

I've had suggestions that this may be a faulty capacitor issue and it's worth sending the motherboard back under warranty. **Does anybody have any suggestions for things to test?** I've also had suggestions of possible RAM failure, but that seems inconsistent with the results.

Tonight I intend to try again with my spare PSU - I did try previously but at the time the board wouldn't boot at *all*. A BIOS reset fixed it that time and by the time I did that I had swapped back to my original PSU. RAM has been tested with memtest with no issues, CPU seems to run fine under a variety of loads and clocks. At the moment it seems to be either PSU or motherboard.

Comment: What is this "unrelated" issue?  Perhaps it is more related than you think.  And I'd fix that first.  Otherwise, yeah, it could be the Mobo, it could just be the PS, it could be a lot of things.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths I consider it unrelated as it happened with the previous two systems in that case - Now that I think of it, could it have something to do with bad case grounding and the mobo having a panic attack about it or something? Enabling power allows static to drain through the ground? I'm not sure. But I agree, it could be basically anything, but that's why I'm everything before start sending off bits that work fine for repair.

Comment: If the old PS worked fine, then your current PS probably is the culprit.  I had a brand new PS that failed after only a few days use, initially I blamed the mobo, based on the issues I had.  Try your spare PS again.  If the issues are the same/still exist, then the PS isn't the problem.